# Run or send a command to a tmux pane in a running tmux session

Tags: bash, shell, tmux

I want to write a shell script which will attach to a named tmux session, select a window (or pane) in that session and run a command in that selected window (or pane).

How do I do this from a bash script?

I know

```
tmux new-window -n:mywindow 'exec something'
```

allows me to send commands to a freshly created window, but I need something like

```
tmux select-window -t:0 'my command'
```

I suppose I could use `send-keys` but seems like there should be something that takes a command or list of commands that get run.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Each *tmux* pane is an interface for a single pty (pseudo tty). Non-split windows have a single pane; split windows have multiple panes.

*tmux* does not supply a way to add extra processes to a pane once it has been started with its initial command. It is up to that initial command’s process (usually a shell) to supply job control<sup>1</sup> for that terminal.

If you want to clobber whatever is currently running in the pane, you can use `respawn-pane -k` to kill the existing command and replace it with a new one (e.g., `respawn-pane -t sessionname:0.4 -k 'some -new command'`).

But, if you want to maintain whatever is currently running in the pane, then there may be no better option that simply “typing at it” with `send-keys`.

You might script it like this (attach last, because otherwise the script will just wait for you to detach before continuing):

```
session=whatever
window=${session}:0
pane=${window}.4
tmux send-keys -t "$pane" C-z 'some -new command' Enter
tmux select-pane -t "$pane"
tmux select-window -t "$window"
tmux attach-session -t "$session"
```

Note that, on the `send-keys` command, you should actually type the letters
<kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd>,
to tell `tmux` to send a newline key to the window. 
(Naturally, every command ends with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Job control is the arbitration between multiple process groups of a single session that uses the tty as its controlling terminal. I.e., the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> suspend key, and the `jobs`, `fg`, and `bg` shell commands.

Comment: Thanks for this! I put `#{session_name}:#{window_index}.#{pane_index}` in my status line so I can quickly see which pane to send commands to.

Comment: That's nice to prevent the window to be removed when the command returns.

Answer (score 22):

You can use `C-m` instead of `Enter`. It's the same thing. Also, `tmux` makes it easy to send to the right / left pane by using `-t right` or `-t left`. And if you want to address a pane in another window, just prefix it with the window number and period, like `-t 0.right`.

Now you can write a simple Bash function to get the sequence of keys as argument and send it over to the target pane easily.

Comment: You can also use `select-pane -t {last}` for the last (previous) active pane.

Answer (score 1):

**Add commands to a simple text file queue:**

This is only a last resort, if you really wanted to run the command after the last one without killing it.

Example

1. Write a bash script that takes a [cli command] and a [tmux pane name] as variables
2. The script adds the command to a queue file which it titles to pertain to that pane only
3. However the queue file's first line is merely a 0 or 1
4. The script loops through simple attempt at changing the 0 to a 1 **via a tmux send-keys command to the corresponding tmux pane**. (If there is a command presently running in the pane, the send-keys command *naturally* does nothing. Otherwise, it changes the 0 to a 1.)
5. In the same loop, the script then attempts to detect a 1 in the queue file.
6. When the script detects that the 0 is a 1, it runs the next command in the queue, and deletes it from the file. It changes the 1 back to a 0.

To store commands, you could also use an "associative array"

The script stops looping when the array is empty.