# Send a command to the currently attached tmux session from a bash script

Tags: bash, tmux

I am inside a fresh tmux session called `mysession`, and I would like to split the window from the command line. I have read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/492266/run-or-send-a-command-to-a-tmux-pane-in-a-running-tmux-session) post, but can't get the solution to work.

When I call this from within the session:

```
tmux split-window -t mysession
```

...i get the following output, and no split window:

```
sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force
```

I have tried using `-t mysession:0` and `-t mysession:0.0`.

When I use the following:

```
tmux -t mysession split-window
```

I get this result, and no split window:

```
command or window name given with target
```

To restate the issue: I am inside of a tmux session sitting at the prompt, and I would like to run one command that splits the window in half. This command is run in the actual shell created by tmux, not by `C-b :` or any tmux keyboard shortcut. Is something like this possible?